# Primes are uniformly distributed

Tags: number-theory

Is the following true?

————————————————–

Primes are uniformly distributed

Let p, r, n are positive integers with p>1.

U(p, r, n) denotes the number of primes less than n that are equal to r (mod p).

For any prime p and pair of integers r1, r2 between 1 and p-1, we have:

The ratio U(p,r1,n) / U(p,r2,n) has limit 1 as n goes to infinity.

Comment: The limit is $1$ but one can also say interesting things about how often it is below or above $1$.  See the references here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the distribution of primes modulo $n$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403919/what-is-the-distribution-of-primes-modulo-n) also answered here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68981/primes-sum-ratio

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true. It is a strengthening of the Prime Number Theorem  to primes in arithmetic progressions.

More is true. Let $m$ be a positive integer, not necessarily prime. Let $a$ and $a'$ be numbers relatively prime to $m$. Then the ratio of the number of primes $\le n$ of the form $mk+a$ to the number of primes $\le n$ of the form $mk+a'$ approaches $1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions .

Comment: Slightly more relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions