# Asymptotic equality of single prime distributions

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Consider $3 \ | \ k, \ k \ge 3$. If $p_R = k + 2$ is a prime, denote it a regular single prime, and if $p_L = k + 4$ is prime, an irregular single prime. Intuitively, with $n \to \infty$ the number of regular and irregular single primes in the range $p \le n$ should be equal: $(N_R(n) - N_L(n))/N_R(n) \to 0, \ n \to \infty$.

Is it a known statement and if so how is it proven?

Comment: This seems convoluted.  Are you just looking at primes congruent to $2$ or to $1$ $\pmod 3$?  If so, then [Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) tells us that the two have equal densities.

Comment: Despite of Chebycheff's biase (non-residues tend to be prefered), in the long run the ratio of both kind of primes will tend to $1/2$. For a similar prime race ($4k+1$ versus $4k+3$) it has been shown that the lead switches infinite many often and I guess this is the case here as well.

Comment: Nevertheless, both numbers will rarely be exactly equal. The difference between them does NOT converge to $0$. In fact, the numbers cannot be equal if we have an odd number of primes we have checked. So, you have to reformulate the conjecture.

Comment: Correct, there will be an infinite number of positions with $N_R \ne N_L$, the statement has been corrected.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68981/primes-sum-ratio ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks. Probably I misunderstand something in: "If a,d are coprime, then the asymptotic proportion of primes congruent to a modulo d is equal to 1/φ(d), where φ is the totient function" but let's consider sequences: 1) S1: a = 1, d = 6; 2) S2: a = 5, d = 6. Clearly 1) a, d are coprime 2) S1, S2 are mutually exclusive and 3) contain all primes > 5. Then by the theorem the proportion of primes in a sufficiently large range $x$ would be $\sim \frac{2}{6φ(6)}$ and how would that agree with the PNT?

Comment: The statement you quoted is understood to be giving (asymptotic) proportions *among the primes*. That is, if you look *only at the prime numbers*, then the proportion congruent to $a$ modulo $d$ is $1/\phi(d)$. So, half the primes are $1\bmod6$, and half are $5\bmod6$ (asymptotically).

Comment: @GerryMyerson, makes sense thanks.