# Generalization of the Prime number theorem to $\sum_{p\leq x}p^{m+1}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does $ \sum_{p\lt x} p^{-s} $ grow asymptotically for $ \mathrm{Re}(s) \lt 1 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-mathrmres-1)

from the prime number theorem is it possible to have

$$ \sum_{p \le x}\: x^{m} = \frac{ \text{Li}\: (x^{m+1})}{m+1} $$ ?

here 'Li' is the logarithmic integral $ \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{logt} $

valid for m > -1 in the case m=0 we recover the usual prime number theorem.

Comment: I guess you mean *asymptotically* equal there.

Comment: @Anon: That is really funny, I remembered typing this up before, and was about to go find that answer!  It is an exact duplicate, so I am voting to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you meant $\sum_{p\leq x} p^m$ since $\sum_{p\leq x} x^m=x^m \pi(x)$.  In this case when $\text{Re}(s)>-1$ we have $$\sum_{p\leq x}p^{s}=\text{li}\left(x^{1+s}\right)+O\left(\frac{x^{1+s}}{1+s}e^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}\right)$$ where the error is uniform over $s$.  This follows from partial summation and the prime number theorem, please [see this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-mathrmres-1/49434#49434)

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, the real part of $s$ should be greater the $-1$ since the sum converges when it is less then $-1$, and acts different when it equals $1$.  (Specfically we need that $1+s>0$ so the $\text{li}(x^{1+s})$ term contributes.

Comment: This is true if the real part of $s$ exceeds $-1$, as in the original question; otherwise the sum converges except at $s=-1$ itself, so the main term would change.