# Estimate for sum of negative powers of primes

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Specifically, for $a \in (0,1)$, I am interested in the sum $$\sum_{p\leq n} \frac{1}{p^a} $$ as $n$ grows.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer: [How does $ \sum_{p<x} p^{-s} $ grow asymptotically for $ \text{Re}(s) < 1 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-textres-1/49434#49434) Specifically, using partial summation I prove that:

> **Asymptotic:** For $k>-1$ we have
>   $$\sum_{p\leq x}p^{k}=\text{li}\left(x^{k+1}\right)+O\left(x^{k+1}e^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}\right).$$

Where $\text{li}(x)=\int_2^x \frac{1}{\log t}dt$ is the [logarithmic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function).

There was also this follow up question:

- [Does the correctness of Riemann's Hypothesis imply a better bound on $\sum \limits_{p<x}p^{-s}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95058/does-the-correctness-of-riemanns-hypothesis-imply-a-better-bound-on-sum-limi?rq=1)

This gets asked a lot on Math.Stackexchange. Here are some of the duplicates:

- [Finding an asymptotic for the sum $\sum_{p\leq x}p^m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231380/a-conjecture-of-mine-about-primes?lq=1)
- [Generalization of the Prime number theorem to $\sum_{p\leq x}p^{m+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72796/generalization-of-the-prime-number-theorem?lq=1)