# Maximum of least common multiple of numbers whose sum is fixed

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be given. What is the maximal value of the least common multiple of $x_1, \ldots, x_k$, all positive integers, when

$$x_1 + \ldots + x_k = n \: ,$$
and what is the asymptotic value of $\max( \mathrm{LCM}( x_1, \ldots, x_k))$?

Here's what I've found: We need to set $x_1, \ldots , x_k$ to as many prime numbers as possible. So if, say, $n=5$, we set $5 = 2 + 3 $ with $\mathrm{LCM}(2,3) =6$, and if $n=10$, we set $10 = 2+3+5$, $\mathrm{LCM}(2,3,5)=30$.

The sum of all prime numbers less than $x$ are

$$\sum_{p \leq x} p \approx \mathrm{Li} (x^2)  ,$$
(see [What is the sum of the prime numbers up to a prime number $n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623872/what-is-the-sum-of-the-prime-numbers-up-to-a-prime-number-n) , where Li is the logarithmic integral), and the product of prime numbers less than $x$ is given by the primorial function:

$$\prod_{p \leq x } p \approx \exp{x}$$
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial#Definition_for_natural_numbers ). Combining these formulas, I get

$$\max( \mathrm{LCM}( x_1, \ldots, x_k) \approx \exp \left( \sqrt{ \mathrm{Li}^{-1} ( n) } \right) $$
but is this correct?