# Approximation of Products of Truncated Prime $\zeta$ Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, asymptotics, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

The problem arose, while I was looking at products of power [prime zeta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function)
$$
P_x(ks)=\sum_{p\,\in\mathrm{\,primes}\leq x} p^{-ks},
$$
with $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $s=it$ with real $t$. 
By using ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95058/19341))
$$
\sum_{p\leq x}p^{-s}= \mathrm{li}(x^{1-s}) + O \left( {2|s|x^{1/2}}\log x \right)
$$
I get (omitting the error terms for the moment)
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
P_x(ks)P_x(ms) &\sim& 
\text{li}(x^{1-ks})\text{li}(x^{1-ms})
&=&\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln( x^{1-ks} u_k) \ln(x^{1-ms}u_m)} du_k du_m\\
&=&{\rm Ei}(1-ks){\rm Ei}(1-ms)&&\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
How can I simplify this expression? Non-trivial approximations are also welcome, when bounds are given.

**Convolution:**
Since $\text{li}(x^{1-s})=\int_0^{x^{1-s}}(\ln u)^{-1}du$, I thought [Integration of Convolutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Integration), with something like
$$\int(f*g)(x) \, dx=\left(\int f(x) \, dx\right)\left(\int g(x) \, dx\right)
$$
might help, since my problem also deals with products of integrals?

**Special Case:**
When I allow negative values for $k$ and $m$ and set $m=-k$ and get the following
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
P_x(ks)P_x(-ks)&=&\pi(x) + \sum_{j<m}2\cos (\ln \frac{p_j}{p_k})\\
&\sim& \frac{x^{2}}{(1-ks)(1+ks)(\log x)^2}=\frac{1}{(1-(k|s|)^2)}\frac{x^{2}}{(\log x)^2}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
The approximation has only real value, as the original expression had. The following function has the same approximation
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{\left(1-(k|s|\right)^2)} \text{li}^2(x),\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
which would very wealky support something like
$$
P_x(ks)P_x(-ks) \sim \int_0^{x^{1-ks}} \frac{1}{\ln u} du\int_0^{x^{1+ks}} \frac{1}{\ln u} du \sim K(k,s)\times \left(\int_0^{x} \frac{1}{\ln u} du\right)^2 .
$$
Does this give anybody a hint?

Answer (score 3):

After all I can at least give a partial result and a possible path way to a full solution. I think the question could be settled if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/107228/19341) Question on (Semi) Prime Counting Functions could be settled. Let's start with the simple case $k=m=1$ and assume $x$ very large:

$P_x(s)^2$ runs over all semi-primes. So along to the line of thought [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49434/19341), I continue like that:
$$
P_x(s)^2 = \int_2^x t^{-s} d(2\pi_2(t)-\pi(t^{1/2}))=2\left(t^{-s}\pi_2(t)\biggr|_{2}^{x}+s\int_{2}^{x}t^{-s-1}\pi_2(t)dt\right)-\left(t^{-s}\pi(t^{1/2})\biggr|_{2}^{x}+s\int_{2}^{x}t^{-s-1}\pi(t^{1/2})dt\right),
$$
where $\pi_2(t)$ counts all 2-almost primes. The second (-) part is already solved in the linked answer. For the first part there are 2 options:

1. Putting in the asymptotic $\pi_2(t)\sim \left( \frac{t}{\log t} \right) \log\log t$, I get
   $$
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   P_x(s)^2&\sim& C_1 +s\int_{2}^{x}\left( \frac{t^{-s}\log\log t}{\log t} \right) dt\\
   &=& C_1 + s\int_{2}^{x^{1-s}}\left( \frac{\log\frac{\log u}{1-s}}{\log u} \right) du\\
   &=& C_1 + s\int_{2}^{x^{1-s}}\left( \frac{\log\log u}{\log u} \right) du-s\int_{2}^{x^{1-s}}\left( \frac{\log(1-s)}{\log u} \right) du\\
   \end{eqnarray*}
   $$ 
   with $t=u^{1/(1-s)}$. Here I got stuck with the first integral.
2. Using $\pi_2(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{\pi(t^{1/2})}\left[\pi\left(\frac{t}{p_i}\right)-i+1\right]$  to get
   $$
   P_x(s)^2 = C_2 + s\int_{2}^{x}t^{-s-1}  \sum_{i=1}^{\pi(t^{1/2})}\left[\pi\left(\frac{t}{p_i}\right)-i+1\right] dt .
   $$
   Also here I'm unsure how to continue: Is it possible to switch summation and integration?

As a non-expert, I'm not sure, if I can adapt the line of thought [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49434/19341) that easy. But if I'm not wrong, I think this may be extended to all cases of interest by choosing the correct counting function. Another question concerned with that problem can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/106130/19341).

...to be continued...

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively (from the viewpoint of Fourier Analysis),
I would expect the prime zeta function $P(s)=\zeta_P(s)$
to be undefined on the imaginary axis, as argued below.
Wikipedia says that "singularities cluster near all points of"
the line $\Re s=0$, which also bounds the critical strip
of the (full) Riemann zeta function on the left in the complex plane.

Perhaps you should call the partial sums (over $p\leq x$),
which you are treating, the "incomplete" or "truncated"
prime zeta function.

For $s=it$ with $0\neq t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0\neq k\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
p^{-ks}=e^{-ikt\log p}=\cos(kt\log p)-i\sin(kt\log p)
$$
so that for a fixed $k$, the sum over primes $p$
$$
P(ks)
=\sum_{p\text{ prime}}p^{-ks}
=\sum_{p}e^{-ikt\log p}
=\sum_{p}e^{-ik\theta_p}
$$
should behave like a "[random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)" with unit (or "[quantum](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0303081)") steps
but whose directions $-k\theta_p$ are not discrete but, rather, continuous, "incoherent" or "decoherent" (in the spectral/polarization/quantum [physical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_%28physics%29) sense, in the sense of [compressed sensing](http://dsp.rice.edu/cs), where its significance connects with the concept of basis functions in Fourier analysis, or in the general sense of meaning [uncorrelated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function)), aperiodic and decreasing, since
$$
\theta_p=2\pi
\left(
\frac{t\log p}{2\pi}-\left\lfloor
\frac{t\log p}{2\pi}\right\rfloor
\right)
$$
where the rate of change of direction (modulo $2\pi$ we can ignore the jumps)
$
\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\theta_p=\frac{t}{p}
$
decreases in magnitude (deccelerates) slowly
(and hence the autocorrelation between terms increases)
for $p$ sufficiently large.
Since each $\log p$ is irrational (presumably also transcendental)
and each $\theta_p$ is probably also irrational
(except perhaps for one value of $p$, due to $t$),
the directions never repeat and are therefore dense modulo $2\pi$,
so that the sum or expected value should be undefined.

Compare this with a [Fourier Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) or the [Jacobi Theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Theta_functions).
I would not expect convergence from the sequence of partial sums,
unless some kind of symmetry were exploited (for example between $k$ & $m$)
or imposed in some manner, for example analogously to
[Cauchy principle values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) for improper integrals,
or perhaps some other sort of regularization.
Because of the irrationality of $\log p$ for each $p$,
I also would not expect any such symmetry trick for $m,n$
as one sees for example when computing that
$\{e^{inx}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ form an orthonormal basis
in [Hilbert space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Hilbert_space_interpretation).

If we were given a function $f\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$
so that the sequence of Fourier coefficients
$\{c_k=\hat{f}\}$ in $\mathbb{C}$
tended toward zero as $k\rightarrow\pm\infty$,
then we could form a convergent Fourier series
and interchange the order of summations
in the double summation below to obtain
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}c_kP(ks)=
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}
\sum_{p}c_ke^{-ik\theta_p}=
\sum_{p}
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}
c_ke^{-ik\theta_p}=
\sum_{p}f(-\theta_p),
$$
but this would not be allowed for $c_k\equiv1$
since then $f$ would not be integrable.

The truncated sums of $P(ks)$,
except for being deterministic (and the angles $\theta_p$ being aperiodic),
also bear some resemblance to [quantum random walks](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0303081)
(see the discussion around equation 44 in the linked introductory paper).
A characteristic difference between classical and quantum random walks
is that the expected value $\mathbb{E}|X_n|$
is $O(\sqrt n)$ for classical, but $O(n)$ for quantum random walks,
i.e. QRWs are [ballistic rather than diffusive](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/2009-SS/lec04.pdf).
In this context, it would be interesting to see
if your results show ballistic-diffusive "crossover".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but maybe I didn't point out that the sum runs just over all primes less than $x$. But nevertheless it sounds interesting. What do you mean by "$P(s)$ behaves like a random walk with incoherent direction"?

Comment: Thanks, I did not see that the sum was truncated (did you add this subsequently??). I added some explanation and links relating "coherence" to "correlation" and "incoherence" to what we observe here as well as to its analagous roles in compressed sensing (where it plays a similar role to orthogonal bases in Fourier analysis) and quantum physics (where Quantum decoherence has to do with predictability of a system on a macroscopic level when the quantum effects "cancel out" -- exactly what we might hope of this infinite sum).

Comment: After your answer, I added the $\leq x$ to the very first equation, but it was always in the second line. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the suggested title.

Comment: Sorry for not noticing it then, and kudos for some cool math! I would also recommend indicating in some way that it is not $P(ks)$, but also depends on $x$: $P_x(ks)$?