# Finding an asymptotic for the sum $\sum_{p\leq x}p^m$

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does $ \sum_{p \leq x} p^{-s} $ grow asymptotically for $ \text{Re}(s) < 1 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-textres-1)

What could I use to prove the following conjecture?

$ \sum_{p \le x} p^{m} \sim \operatorname{Li}(x^{m+1}) $

For $ m=0 $ this is just the prime number theorem, but would it be true for other numbers 'm' ? Or even for negative m?

Also if the function can be expanded in power series $ f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a(n)x^{n} $,

I also think that $ \sum _{p \le x}f(x) \sim \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a(n)\operatorname{Li}(x^{n+1}) $.

Of course $ \operatorname{Li}(x)= \int_{2}^{x}\frac{du}{\ln(u)} $.

Comment: Did you test that computationally at least? Why do you think this is true?

Comment: It seems your question mark key is stuck?

Comment: I think you are interested in this: [How does $ \sum_{p<x} p^{-s} $ grow asymptotically for $ \text{Re}(s) < 1 $?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/49383/19341) and the answer given therein...

Comment: @Jose, where'd you get this from?

Comment: i got it intuitively for example formthe prime number theorem $ \sum_{n\le x}f(n) \sim \int_{2}^{x} f(x)/ln(x) $ , the probability of finding a prime is about $ \frac {1}{ln(x)} $ and i replace the sum by an integral, which can be obtained in a closed form in terms of the $ Li(x) $ integral at least when $ f(x)= x^{m} $

Comment: @JoseGarcia: see below for a somewhat-proof.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not an answer but a plot for $m=1,2,3,10,20$ because some peopel asked for that.

EDIT: This is somewhat an answer now, see below.

I entered the following code in Mathematica:

```
m = 1
maxx = 100
p1 = DiscretePlot[Sum[Prime[n]^m, {n, PrimePi[x]}], {x, maxx}];
p2 = DiscretePlot[LogIntegral[x], {x, maxx}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[{p1, p2}]
```

It seems alright for small $m$, as you can see below.

---

Okay, so in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-6/issue-1/Approximate-formulas-for-some-functions-of-prime-numbers/10.1215/ijm/1255631807.full) we find that:
$$\sum_{p\leq x\text{ prime}}f(p)\approx\int_2^x \frac{f(y)dy}{\ln y}$$

Substituting $f(p)=p^m$ gives, according to [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20y%5En/%28ln%20y%29):
$$\sum_{p\leq x\text{ prime}}p^m\approx \text{Ei}((n+1)\ln x)= \text{Ei}(\ln x^{n+1})=\text{Li}(x^{n+1})$$

---

$m=1$
[image: m=1]
$m=2$
[image: m=2]
$m=3$
[image: m=3]
$m=10$
[image: m=10]
$m=20$, $maxx=10000$
[image: m=20]