# Does $\sum_{p \leq x} 1/p - \log \log x$ converge as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: number-theory

It is known that 
$$\sum_{p \leq x} 1/p - \log(\log(x)) = O(1)$$ 
(where $p$ denotes that the denominators vary over the primes. For example see Ribenboim, *The Book of Prime Number Records*, 2nd ed., p. 333.) But is it also known that 
$$\sum_{p \leq x} 1/p - \log(\log(x))$$ converges as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does $ \sum\_{p<x} p^{-s} $ grow asymptotically for $ \text{Re}(s) < 1 $?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-textres-1)

Answer (score 4):

Yes.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{p\le n}\frac1p
&=\sum_{k=2}^n(\pi(k)-\pi(k-1))\frac1k\\
&=\frac{\pi(n)}{n}+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\pi(k)\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)\\
&=O\left(\frac1{\log(n)}\right)
+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\left(\frac{k}{\log(k)}
+O\left(\frac{k}{\log(k)^2}\right)\right)\frac1{k(k+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac1{k\log(k)}
+O\left(\frac1{\log(n)}\right)
+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}O\left(\frac1{k\log(k)^2}\right)\\
&=\log(\log(n))+C+O\left(\frac1{\log(n)}\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $C$ is the [Meissel-Mertens constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See [Mertens second theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems).

Comment: Let $p_n$ be the $n^{th}$ prime. My calculations suggest that possibly $\sum_{n=1}^{N} 1/p_n - \log \log N = O(1)$ as well. Is this known? If so, is it also known that $\sum_{n=1}^{N} 1/p_n - \log \log N$ converges too?

Comment: @user88693 What do you know about $\log\log p_N - \log\log N = \log\frac{\log p_N}{\log N}$?  Hint: $p_N < 2N \log N$ for all large enough $N$.