# prime zeta function when $0<s<1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, summation, asymptotics, zeta-functions

I would like  to know if there is a good estimate for the sum which concerns all primes not exceeding $x$:
 $$\sum\limits_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p^s}$$$$0<s<1$$.
Only this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: _Hint:_ $$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{n^s} - \frac{x^{1-s}}{1-x} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{x^{\Re[s]}}\right)$$ Mimic the usual proof of Merten's theorem by logging the Euler product of $\zeta$ and expanding.

Comment: @BalarkaSen is it possible to help me a little bit?I am having some trouble bounding the sum from above...

Comment: Does this question differ from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-textres-1 ?

Comment: @anon i suppose not.Thank you so very much!!