# The asymptotic behavior of the sum of inverse powers of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

The sum asymptotics  when $x\to \infty$, obviously,  must be a function of two variables, $x$ and $s$ :

$$\sum\limits_{p\leqslant x}^{}\frac{1}{p^s}=F(x,s)$$

However, as for the sum of  inverse powers of prime numbers, this function is remarkable of the presence of the self-similiarity, that is, if we denote $ \pi (x) $ - prime counting function, then for the  asymptotic behavior of the sum , apparently, will have:

$$F(x,s)=\sum\limits_{p\leqslant x}^{}\frac{1}{p^s}=\pi(x^{1/(1-s)})$$

This formula was confirmed experimentally in the range of $0\leqslant s <1$ and it follows from a known approximation $\pi(x)$ by  logarithmic integral function. Obviously, this property is about to be discussed somewhere, I would like to read about this in more detail.

Yes, I made a mistake, not $\pi(x^{1/(1-s)})$ but $\pi(x^{(1-s)})$:
$$F(x,s)=\sum\limits_{p\leqslant x}^{}\frac{1}{p^s}=\pi(x^{(1-s)})$$

Comment: You may take a look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-textres-1/49434#49434

Comment: Marco Cantarini, thanks for the link, but I also would like to see some speculations about the consequences of the self-similarity of this function in  broader sense (for example, self-similarity concept is widely used in phase transition theory in physics)