# What is the (asymptotic) sum of the squares of the first $n$ primes?

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, asymptotics

What is the sum of the squares of the first $n$ primes - in other words, what is:

$$\sum_{p=1}^n{ \left( \text{Prime}(p)^2 \right)}$$

Of course we're looking for the asymptotic bounds, not an actual formula.

Comment: cf. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/216343/asymptotic-of-the-sum-of-squared-primes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does $ \sum_{p&lt;x} p^{-s} $ grow asymptotically for $ \text{Re}(s) &lt; 1 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-textres-1)

Comment: @ClementC.:  First off, thanks for the links.  I wonder, though - do you think that there's any chance of eliminating the Logarithmic integral?  I'm trying to relate this sum to another sum, and the $\text{Li}(x)$ function makes it difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: What do you mean by "eliminating it"? It's there, we cannot ignore that -- do you mean replacing it by something equivalent but more convenient?

Comment: @ClementC.:Yes, that's what I meant - I'd like to replace it.  I could have sworn I'd seen bounds on it as a polynomial in $n$ and $\log{(n)}$ only, but I've been searching for this link for hours without luck.  From my notes, I have something on a book by Eric Bach and Jeffrey Shallit, but I don't have anything else besides this.

Comment: Well, $\operatorname{Li}(x^3) \sim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^3}{3\ln(x)}$, so there is that :)

Comment: By summation by parts and the PNT

$$ \sum_{x\leq N} x^2 \mathbb{1}_{\text{prime}}(x)\approx\frac{N^3}{\log N}-\sum_{2\leq x\leq N-1}\frac{x(2x+1)}{\log x}=\frac{N^3}{3\log N}+O\left(\frac{N^3}{\log^2 N}\right) $$

Comment: @ClementC.:  That's all I really need.  I will upvote if you put this in an answer and add references.  I'm split between your comments and Jack D'Aurizio's, so I don't know who to accept.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio:  If you can put this in an answer and cite references, I will upvote it.  Again, I'm split between your math and Clement C.'s

Comment: @MattGroff: you can find a very detailed proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-textres-1/49434#49434

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio:  Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, if we denote the nth prime by $p_n$ then $p_n \sim n \log n$ by the PNT, so $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k^2 \sim \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k \log k)^2 \sim \int_0^n (x\log x)^2\,dx \sim \frac{n^3 (\log n)^2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-textres-1) (and the [MathOverflow post linking to it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/216343/asymptotic-of-the-sum-of-squared-primes)), we have as a direct consequence of the Prime Number Theorem that
$$
\sum_{\substack{p\text { prime}\\ p\leq n}} p^2 = \operatorname{Li}(n^3)+ O(n^3e^{-c\sqrt{\ln x}})\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^3}{3\ln n}
$$
for some constant $c>0$, where $\operatorname{Li}$ is the logarithmic integral.

Comment: @MattGroff For the sake of closure, if that settles it consider accepting the answer. (If not, of course don't.)