# How fast does $\prod_{p\leq x}\frac 1{1-p^{-k}}$ diverge when $0<k<1$?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

We have that

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n\log(\log(n))}=e^\gamma$$

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\log(\tau(n))\frac{\log(\log(n))}{\log(n)}=\log(2).$$

I'm trying to find a similar result for $\sigma_k$ for $0<k<1$. The two results above correspond to the ends of the interval $\tau=\sigma_0$ and $\sigma=\sigma_1$. For an $n=p_1^{a_1}\dots p_r^{a_r}$,

$$\sigma_k(n)=\prod_{h=1}^r\frac{p_h^{k(a_h+1)}-1}{p_h^k-1}$$

$$\frac{\sigma_k(n)}{n^k}=\prod_{h=1}^r\frac{1-p_h^{-k(a_h+1)}}{1-p_h^{-k}}.$$

Each term in the product is a decreasing function of $p_h$, so for this quantity to be large we want the $p_h$ to be small, so assume they're the primes in increasing order $p_1=2$, etc. By choosing all of the $a_h$ to be large the numerators all approach 1, but the behavior of the denominators is more vexing. We have

$$\frac{\sigma_k(n)}{n^k}<\prod_{h=1}^r\frac 1{1-p_h^{-k}}$$

so define

$$f_k(x)=\prod_{p\leq x}\frac 1{1-p^{-k}}.$$

It seems reasonable to conjecture that $\frac{\sigma_k(n)}{n^k}$ is close to $f_k(p_r)$, that is, that the the above inequality is tight. This is why I want an asymptotic form for $f_k$.

I did some numerical computation for the $k=\frac 12$ case. Plotting $\log(f_{1/2})$ on a log-log plot got me a surprisingly linear-looking relationship, which corresponds to

$$f_{1/2}(x)\approx e^{x^\alpha}$$

where $\alpha=0.3751988607236585$. Other than guessing this is three eights, I don't know.

[image]

I tried using the Euler product

$$\sum_{n=1}^x\frac 1{n^k}<f_k(x)$$

but it appears this inequality is far from tight, as the left-hand side is asymptotically polynomial.

Comment: For $k\in (0,1)$ the PNT gives $\sum_{p\le x} p^{-k} \sim \sum_{n\le x} \frac{n^{-k}}{\log n} \sim \frac{x^{1-k}}{(1-k)\log x}$.
Under the RH for $k\in (1/2,1)$ it is $O(1)+\sum_{n\le x} \frac{n^{-k}}{\log n}$.

Comment: @Gary Your formula and linked post are wrong

Comment: @reuns Thanks. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/49434) is a better reference.